# How can I solve DNS delay on iOS over VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, sonicwall, ios

When connecting iOS devices to our Sonicwall VPN (L2TP) it takes about 30 seconds before any internal servers can be contacted. It appears to be purely a DNS problem because they can be contacted via IP address. This issue does not exist on Mac or PC desktops/laptops.

Comment: I have observed the same behavior on iOS and OS X and we are tunneling all traffic.

Comment: I have tried flipping the all traffic switch with no change in behavior.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lack of clarity but we experience the same behavior regardless of tunnel all or not. I have not been able to find a solution as of yet.

Comment: My above post was in error, i missed the iOS part. This is for the os x client

Answer (score 2):

It's an IPV6 issue, if you go to console and open your ppp log you will notice an IPv6 query every 3 seconds until it times out. You need to tell the ppp daemon to not try IPv6. To do this create a text file called options.txt with the following string: ipv6cp-max-configure 0  Save that file to the etc/ppp directory. You need to be root or sudo cp it via terminal. Reboot and your problem should go away.